# Code running fine in my computer but NullPointerException when running online on platforn of "hackerearth"

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I was trying problems on hackerearth.com and in one program, `NullPointerException` is coming, but when I am running that code in my computer, it is running fine. I have read a lot about null pointer exception but could not under stand why that exception is coming.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String arr2[] = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    String s = br.readLine();
    String arr[] = s.trim().split("\\s+");
    int arr1[] = new int[arr.length];
}
```

This the part where exception is coming at --> `String arr[]=s.trim().split("\\s+");`

Comment: s might be null because br.ReadLine() reads from un unreachable input stream or that stream is at EOF

Comment: so what can i do to avoid this, can u suggest?, i used br.readLine () many times when i have to take integer output from single line with spaces in between , but it never showed any exception , just in this case.

Comment: you can check ```if (s != null)```, before the lines ```String arr[]... ``` and ```int arr1[]...``` this all may be caused by a closed connection. And I thought this was c#, but maybe java ? please add an according tag!

Comment: it is in java, so every time i have to use readLine(), i have to check ?

Comment: I would do so, yes.

Comment: There is another question about something very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457931/what-is-the-reason-for-my-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up my comments. The code would look like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String arr2[] = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    String s = br.readLine();
    if (s != null)
    {
        String arr[] = s.trim().split("\\s+");
        int arr1[] = new int[arr.length];
        // do something with arr1
    }
    else
    {
        // maybe leave the loop with break;
    }
}
```